# How to print all columns and rows from a csv file's min and max value in python

Tags: python, csv, data-science

I have to print out the min/max values from a specific column, which I was able to do. But I also need to show the data from all the columns of the min/max fields.

below is the code:

```
import csv

with open('phone_data.csv','r') as p_data:
data = csv.reader(p_data, delimiter=',')
next(data)
d_col = list(data)

minTemp = min([float(elem[2]) for elem in d_col])
maxTemp = max([float(elem[2]) for elem in d_col])
print("min value is: ", minTemp)
print("max value is: ", maxTemp)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should sort the rows (stored in `d_col`) with the third item as the key instead:

```
import csv

with open('phone_data.csv','r') as p_data:
    data = csv.reader(p_data, delimiter=',')
    next(data)
    d_col = list(data)

min_row = min(d_col, key=lambda row: float(row[2]))
max_row = max(d_col, key=lambda row: float(row[2]))
print("min row is: ", min_row)
print("max row is: ", max_row)
```

Comment: Also, say I have 4 networks, (tmobile, verizon etc) and I wanted to know how many calls each network received. Data is in the same csv file. How would i go about doing that? I'm not allowed to use PANDAS, so I'm having difficulty searching through rows and columns with python and applying sum/counts.

Comment: @UmairAhmed No problem. For your further question though it's best to post as a new question since it involves quite a bit of sample input and sample output and possibly some of your current code. I and the others will be more than glad to help.